# R Remove upper and lower percentile from SpatialLines (DataFrame)

Tags: r, spatial-statistics

How can I make a selection depending on the statistics of a SpatialLinesDataFrame in R?

The goal is to select and subset the lower and upper quartile of a data frame at once.

Comment: What have you tried, and what happens when you try it?  Please [edit] your question to include more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `quantile` in a bracket query to subset your features. In this example we subset based on the first and third quartile using the cadmium column. If you have a continuous range then use `&` but, if we wanted to subset the lower and upper ranges then we would use `|`.

```
library(sp)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y
```

Susbset below/above the first and third quartiles [p < 0.25 and p > 0.75] since they are two different ranges we use an "or" statement with the `|`

```
meuse.sub <- meuse[meuse$cadmium > quantile(meuse$cadmium, p = 0.75) | 
                   meuse$cadmium < quantile(meuse$cadmium, p = 0.25),]
  sort(meuse.sub$cadmium)
```

Susbset within the first and third quartiles [p > 0.25 and p < 0.75], thus removing values below and above. Since they are a continuous range we use an "and" statement with the `&`

```
meuse.sub <- meuse[meuse$cadmium < quantile(meuse$cadmium, p = 0.75) & 
                   meuse$cadmium > quantile(meuse$cadmium, p = 0.25),]    
 sort(meuse.sub$cadmium)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to answer without a concrete example from your side. The general  answer is: Just in the same way as with a regular data.frame.

Maybe this little example will help, otherwise you'll have to be much more specific with your question:

```
library(sp)
library(rworldmap) # for example data

# load example data:
data(coastsCoarse)
plot(coastsCoarse)

# examine the structure of the Object
str(coastsCoarse, max.level = 3)
# the slot @data is just a good old-fashioned data frame that serves the role of 
# the attribute table in GIS.
head(coastsCoarse@data)

# Let's add some random data to that so we can make a selection based on the data:
coastsCoarse@data$somedata <- rnorm(n = length(coastsCoarse), mean = 0, sd = 3)
head(coastsCoarse@data)

# subsetting now works as with any regular data.frame.
# let's select only the lines where the value of "somevalue" is > 0
foo <- subset(x=coastsCoarse, subset = somedata > 0)

plot(foo)
```

As for the percentiles, have a look at the `quantiles()` command.